# Android - MediaPlayer's on Prepare Called even before the stream is prepared on Android 4.0+

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, media-player, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am facing the issue that whenever a stream is played by my app on Android 4.0+ the `OnPrepare` method from `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` is called even before a stream is loaded and thus i am unable to indicated the user that the stream downloading/buffering is in process. [I have already found a question of the same kind but not answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538013/android-4-0-4-mediaplayer-prepare-issue-using-rtsp-urls)
 Here is a what i am doing.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        playVideo(someRtspUrl);
    }
    private void playVideo(String url) {
        // if app is running on Google TV then change RTSP link to HLS
        if (url.contains("rtsp")) {

            // split the RTSP URL and make it as HLS
            String videoUrlParts[] = url.split("\\?");
            url = videoUrlParts[0].replace("rtsp", "http") + "/playlist.m3u8";

            if (videoUrlParts.length > 1)
                url += "?" + videoUrlParts[1];
        }   mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this); 

    }



    @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            mVideoView.start();
        }
```

**This Code is Working fine on Google TV and other Android 3.0+ and < 4.0+ device**

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with media player. But couple of suggestions/queries from my side

1. No call to prepare. If you are doing it, did you try prepareAsync ?
2. You are not using the mediaplayer instance which is passed to the onPrepared callback. There can be a chance that you are trying to start the wrong mediaplayer.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestions/Queries @gvmani. for the second one i would say that i am playing the orignal/main object. for the 1st one. prepare synchronously is also working. the issue is on specific OS

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) class that is available. Unlike the [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) is aware of its state and manages even more things for you that [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) doesn't offer.. Paired with setting up a [SurfaceHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html) to display the content in it is pretty simple.

You'll just want to make sure that you are properly handling the state and using the prepareAsync() call of MediaPlayer.

Comment: well the issue is that the If Video View is unaware of its state then how it is working fine on Android 3.1 and above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue for .m3u8 with Android < 4.3.

They fixed this in 4.3. It will be worth to compare MediaPlayer or VideoView code of different platforms i.e 4.3 & < 4.3

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case .. i i have checked rtsp and other streams too. and for the less than 4.3 case **it works on 3.0 and above uptil before 4.0.4 as mentioned in the question**